# How do I get my text centered below the image, not adjacent to it?

Tags: html, css

In the HTML markup below, what do I need to do in order to get the text, "What is this?" to be positioned BELOW the image? Initially, I placed the text in `<p>` tags but, although the text was positioned correclty, I lost my desired hyperlink behavior.

Thanks!

```
<div class="HorizontallyCentered"> 
    <a href="qr.aspx">
        <img alt="Image of JA10" src="files/ja10.png" height="150" width="150" />
        What is this?
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this css

```
.HorizontallyCentered 
{
    text-align: center   
}
.HorizontallyCentered img
{
  display: block
}
```

that should force the text on to the line below.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to do this is to simply use the `<br />` tag, however HTML/CSS purists would recommend that you set the class **HorizontallyCentered** to be the same width as the ja10.png as using the `<br />` tag to create spacing is not considered ideal.

Comment: <br> is in the strict dtd, fine by me. Perhaps I'm just not purist enough.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, and kind of redundant code im pretty sure this will do the work:

### HTML:

```
<div class="HorizontallyCentered"> 
    <a href="qr.aspx">
        <img alt="Image of JA10" src="files/ja10.png" height="150" width="150" />
        <span>What is this?</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.HorizontallyCentered {
  text-align: center; 
}
.HorizontallyCentered img {
  display: block
}
.HorizontallyCentered span {
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: You've placed a block-level element (`div`) inside of an inline-element (`a`), which renders the (x)html invalid. In this situation a `span` should be used instead of a `div`.