# Center text under icon?

Tags: html, css

Using Font Awesome.
It has some classes that link to specific icons for example:

`.fa-info-circle:before{content:"\f021"}`
`<td class="fa fa-info-circle">`

Now what I'm trying, is to center the text under the image:

`<td class="fa fa-info-circle"><a href="info.html">About Us</a></td>`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604238/how-do-i-get-my-text-centered-below-the-image-not-adjacent-to-it) thread but it only works with img tags, and this doesn't use them.

I tried, though:

```
td.fa-info-circle {
 display: block;
}

table td {
 display: inline; 
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right:auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/y8EB2/

Comment: possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan There

Comment: You want to use a table? I made an edit of your fiddle without table. You are looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/y8EB2/5/ If you want to use a table look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/y8EB2/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8EB2/3/)

```
td.fa-info-circle a
{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use FontAwesome and have all the icons defined in order to use `.fa` and `.fa-info-circle`.

What those classes do is add a pseudo-class selector (`:before`) 
and add an icon as CSS generated content (`content:"\f021"` for example) 
before your real content:

(`<a href="info.html">About Us</a>` in your case).

So in order to center that real content what you need is to tell that generated icon to be block-level element in order to drop the text below:

```
td.fa-info-circle:before {
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/9fT6v/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to align icon not text, because you are using `:before` selector for icon so do like this:

set `position:relative` to your `td`:

```
td.fa-info-circle {
   position:relative;
   padding-top:30px;  /*  as the height of your icon  */
}
```

then edit `.fa-info-circle:before`:

```
.fa-info-circle:before{
    content:"\f021";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;   /*  as the height of your icon  */
    left:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GkPqp/)

---

as your demo:

```
.fa-info-circle:before{
content:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/free-tabs-icons-by-kevin-andersson/png/40x40/Circle-Info.png);
height: 58px;
width: 58px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:50%;
margin-left:-29px;
}

td.fa-info-circle {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:70px;
    min-width:58px;
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y8EB2/4/)

Comment: It works, but it's the most complicated solution in this thread.

Comment: @Claudio yes, jsFiddle makes solutions simple :)